# Can not ExecStart service python script as root on Linux

Tags: linux, python, service, socket

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

I created a service that executes python script **checker.py**. The problem is this service does not execute python script with root privileges, although **sirjay** user has root privileges and, moreover, executing `sirjay $ sudo python checker.py` works.

How I figured out it? This python script does not restart and reboot system when it executes by service (but directly `sirjay $ sudo python checker.py` restarts and reboots):

```python
import os
os.system("sudo systemctl restart other-task")
os.system("sudo reboot")
```

Services:

```
[Unit]
Description=checker.py service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sirjay
# User=root. <-- does not work also
# Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/dir

Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
Environment="PATH=/home/sirjay/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/dir checker.py
StandardOutput=file:/home/dir/service_checker_output.log
StandardError=file:/home/dir/service_checker_error.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't see any errors in service_checker_error.log. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: What does `systemctl status unitname` show?

Comment: Furthermore your unit is littered in mistakes. The period after root in username. The space in ExecStart. Is this in verbatim what the unit file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: `os.system("/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot")`